# MySQL text containing two back slashes

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to insert a composer JSON text into a TEXT column of a MySQL database.

If I insert the following

```html
insert into server_details set composer = '"psr-4": {
                                                "App\\": "app/"
                                }'
```

What is inserted into the database is

```
"psr-4": { "App\": "app/" }
```

Notice only a single back slash after App. How can I insert the composer JSON into a sql database without making the JSON invalid?

Full JSON being inserted is:

```html
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.7",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.10.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.3.0",
    "freshbitsweb/laratables": "^2.4",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.3.0",
    "ignited/laravel-omnipay": "3.3.*",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php": "^2.2.9",
    "laravel/framework": "8.*",
    "laravel/ui": "^v3.3.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^v6.2.1",
    "league/csv": "^9.7.1",
    "milon/barcode": "^8.0",
    "omnipay/sagepay": "3.*",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log": "^8.0",
    "spatie/eloquent-sortable": "^3.11.0",
    "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.17.0",
    "spatie/laravel-newsletter": "^4.10",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^4.2"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.6.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.6.2",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^v2.8.2",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.13",
    "laminas/laminas-code": "^3.4.1",
    "laracasts/generators": "^1.1.8",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5.20",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.1"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": [
      ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Why not use **two** quoted backslashes, making it a total of **four**?

Comment: Provided value is not valid JSON one from MySQL looking point.

Comment: Why do you need a backslash as part of the "key" (I mean, in "App\\")? Normally, you would use the key exactly as such, a "KEY" and not to contain any additional information (my guess is that you are attempting to convey some information within the key-name to be used later on, and that is a wrong approach for OOP/OOD/JSON).

Comment: That is only a snippet of the JSON, but it is the bit that is causing the problem.

Comment: @FDavidov because that's how Composer stores the mapping between PHP class namespaces and folders

Comment: Any string, JSON or not, needs to be escaped somehow so that it could be used inside query. Doubling the backslashes and escaping the `'` symbol is minimum. How are you inserting the data anyway? I am sure you are not typing the insert queries.

Comment: The SQL insert is from a BASH script. I can't seem to convert the // to ////. Hoping that there is a way to insert in to the database without escaping. Something like the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode, although that doesn't seem to work. @SalmanA

Comment: bash also uses backslash for escaping.  You might need 8 backslashes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode  disables black slashes.

if
NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES mode is enabled,  use "App\/";

Comment: This still removes one of the back slashes.                          SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
  
  
insert into server_details set composer = '"psr-4": {
   "App\\": "app/"
  }'

Comment: Can u try App\\/ or App\\/\\/

Comment: Weird, setting it my BASH script seems to have worked, so I will mark that as the answer. Thanks Siva!